# Wishing to run calendar import script on specific sheet not on active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I would like the Google Calendar import script run on a specific sheet. Lets Say "Sheet4"  The script works well on any current active sheet but I seem to be unable to modify all the proper lines in the script to make it work properly to be directed to a specified sheet.

Here is a link to the sheet
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DI_gnXyeKrR_t_6u0-EKzfUjeMmXj8GC6HlU-3uGmkc/edit#gid=2105065853

I tried to paste the code but kept getting formatting error. Apologies in advance. I am very new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared the Google Spreadsheet but you can use the below code snippet to perform task on a particular sheet.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet4");
```

For sheet of different spreadsheet.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<ENTER SPREADSHEET ID>>").getSheetByName("Sheet4")
```